# Как настроить права и роли (области видимости) в Битрикс24?

Tags: php, битрикс, права, crm

В настройках прав доступа Битрикс, раздел CRM, есть Пользователь ТЕСТ с ролью Начальник Отдела.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Управлении этой ролью строка Контакты проставлена на "Свои", чтобы пользователь мог видеть только контакты в пределах своего отдела.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако, в разделе Контакты отображаются данные со всех отделов и от всех менеджеров. Почему так происходит? Нужна ли какая-то дополнительная настройка?

Как выставить так, чтобы дальше своего отдела и контактов, внесённых в нём, человек не смог видеть?

Comment: А пользователь тест не является Администратором? Не входит в группу Руководство? "Свои" означает, что будет видеть только если он ответственный.

Comment: является Админ-ом. не входит в группу Руководство. Как сделать "ответственным"?

Comment: Битрикс присваивает пользователю максимальные из возможных прав. Снимите с пользователя ТЕСТ админские права и все заработает. Администраторы могут видеть все так как у них полные права.